# karma.conf.js automatic file ordering?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a large angularjs project ordered by features. I'd like to setup unit testing but I'm having trouble getting the karma.conf.js file ordering setup.

I tried specifying a simple glob pattern like **/*.js but many of my modules failed to load due to the ordering that they're included in Karma when ran. As I understand, it's alphabetical, first match.

I was able to resolve this by manually figuring out the ordering by doing something like this:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  // External scripts
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',

  // NOTE: ORDER IS IMPORTANT
  // Modules: load module first, then all controllers, services, etc
  'scripts/module1/module1.js',
  'scripts/module1/**/*.js',
  'scripts/module2/module2.js',
  'scripts/module2/**/*.js',

  // Load overall app module last
  'scripts/app.js',

  // Load mocks and tests
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```

This seems like it will be cumbersome to maintain over time as new modules are added. Is there a way to automatically resolve the ordering?

Note: One possible solution I was thinking was to concat all the files together but I googled to see if others are doing this and found no examples.

Comment: Not what you expect has an aswer, but we use requirejs with our big angular app and that has made this problem a non existing one. Maybe updating to an AMD solution like requirejs would help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may look into different solutions here, depending on how you want to manage your project.

### Solution n.1

Use [AMD/RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html): do not load your modules all at once but just require them when you need.
Sometimes it may not fit your needs tough making the project over complicated, so look below.

**Note**: this is IMHO the most elegant solution and karma [does support requireJS](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/requirejs.html).

### Solution n.2

Create a namespace where you append all your stuff and start them when the DOM is ready (usually pretty quick, but it really depends on how much scripts you load)

```
// module A
// Something like this should be fine
(function(){
  window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
  // append things to the namespace...
})();

// module B
(function(){
  window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
  // append things to the namespace...
})();

// This is very rough but it should give the idea
window.ondomready = MyNamespace.start;
```

**Note**: while this may work you have to fiddle a bit with your project to change the structure accordingly.

I would go for the one above unless you really hates requireJS and all the modules stuff.

### Solution n.3

Programmatically order your Karma files: I wrote about it [in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276239/detecting-environment-when-running-karma/24286880#24286880).

**Note**: this is the less mantainable of the options.

Answer (score 0):

If this

```
  // Modules: load module first, then all controllers, services, etc
  'scripts/module1/module1.js',
  'scripts/module1/**/*.js',
  'scripts/module2/module2.js',
  'scripts/module2/**/*.js',
```

could instead force the same filenaming convention on the module-declaration file, to be this

```
  // Modules: load module first, then all controllers, services, etc
  'scripts/module1/moduleDeclaration.js',
  'scripts/module1/**/*.js',
  'scripts/module2/moduleDeclaration.js',
  'scripts/module2/**/*.js',
```

Then you could do this

```
  // Modules: load module first, then all controllers, services, etc
  'scripts/**/moduleDeclaration.js',
  'scripts/**/*.js',
```

I do something similar, though I do break out interfaces & types between moduleDeclaration and "the rest of it".

Answer (score -1):

I use browserify and i have no prblems with it, here is my configuration:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],
    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'dev/**/*Spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    browserify: {
      watch: false,
      debug: true
    },
    preprocessors: {
      'dev/**/*Spec.js': ['browserify']
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: ****,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```