# AngularJS design guide

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Previously when I was writing angular apps, I used to do

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['all', 'required', 'ng*', 'dependencies'])
```

in my `app.js` and then inside `services/` and `controllers`, I could simply do:

```
angular.module('ngApp')
```

I have a [repo](https://github.com/argentum47/angular-store-rails/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js) to demonstrate that.

But then I saw the `angular-seed/`, the way implemented was,

in `controllers/`

```
angular.module('appControllers', ['dependencies'])...
```

in `services/`

```
angular.module('appServices', ['dependencies'])..
```

in app.js

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ng*', 'appControllers', 'appSrvices'])..
```

I had no issue with design, infact I thought it was good, since evrything was dependency injected as well as modular.

I have a situation where I have a `services/movie.js` that has

```
angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource']).factory(..)
```

and `services/config.js`

```
angular.module('myAppServices').factory(..)
```

But while writing tests with karma and jasmine. In the karma.conf.js,

I had 
   `files: ['usual', 'bower_components/angular-*.js', 'app/services/**/*.js', '..']`

but the problem was config.js got loaded before movie.js and there were errors, `myAppServices` is not loaded or mis-spelt.

The way I fixed it was I did:

```
files: ['..', 'app/services/movie.js', 'app/services/config.js']
```

I have set up a [github repo](https://github.com/argentum47/tmdb/tree/unit-tests) for this too. Here is the [controller test file](https://github.com/argentum47/tmdb/blob/unit-tests/unit-tests/controllers/movies_controller_spec.js) and here is the [karma.conf](https://github.com/argentum47/tmdb/blob/unit-tests/karma.conf.js).

I want to know what can be the possible approaches to take such modular approach, without having to specify the order in which the files are to be loaded for my tests.

And this is my first unit test, and its failing:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=2e329c92227ed8be07944ae447c9426f
Expected GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=2e329c92227ed8be07944ae447c9426f
```

It would be helpful if I could get some help in fixing that too.

The test

```
describe('Controllers', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('myAppServices'));

  describe("MoviesCtrl", function() {
    var scope, ctrl, httpBackend;

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope, _$controller_, Movie, Config) {
      httpBackend = $httpBackend;
      ctrl = _$controller_;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    it("should return a list of movies", function() {
      var data = {results: [{name: "Abc"}, {name: "Def"}]};

      httpBackend.
        expectGET("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=2e329c92227ed8be07944ae447c9426f").
        respond(data);
      ctrl('MoviesCtrl', { $scope: scope });
      httpBackend.flush()
      expect(scope.image).toEqual("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/");
    });
  });

});
```

conf. file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/services/movie.js',
      'app/services/config.js',
      'app/controllers/*.js',
      'app/app.js',
      'unit-tests/**/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
      'app/**/*.min.js'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

### UPDATE

I have figured out the error in test, I had to mock the other http request for the configuration. thanks to @Phil.

This is my test now:

```
describe('Controllers', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('myAppServices'));

  describe("MoviesCtrl", function() {
    var scope, httpBackend;
    var config_data = { images: { base_url: "http://tmdb.com/t/p", backdrop_sizes: ["w300", "w500"]}},
        movie_data = {results: [{name: "Abc"}, {name: "Def"}]};

    beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope, $controller) {
      httpBackend = $httpBackend;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
       httpBackend.
        expectGET("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=2e329c92227ed8be07944ae447c9426f").
        respond(config_data);
      httpBackend.
        expectGET("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=2e329c92227ed8be07944ae447c9426f").
        respond(movie_data);
      $controller('MoviesCtrl', { $scope: scope });
    }));

    it("should return a list of movies", function() {
      expect(scope.image).toEqual({})

      httpBackend.flush();

      expect(scope.image.backdrop_size).toEqual("w300");
    });
  });

});
```

Although I am not sure if this is the right test to do :P . Something like a VCR would be helpful.

Comment: One approach would be to move the `myAppServices` into services folder like other service too.

Comment: myAppServices is my module name. it is in app/services https://github.com/argentum47/tmdb/tree/master/app/services . I am making use of the fact, once I have declared my dependencies like https://github.com/argentum47/tmdb/blob/master/app/services/movie.js , the next time I can just do https://github.com/argentum47/tmdb/blob/master/app/services/config.js

Comment: I would move the config stuff into it's own module. I like to stick with a *one-module-per-file* design. Makes testing easy

Comment: As for your failing test, you need to use angular-mocks and mock out **all** the `$http` requests using `$httpBackend`

Comment: I think the [angular-phonecat repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat) uses the same structure as you mention here and use karma for testing, could be worth checking out.

Comment: @hochas I did, and their tests pass mine doesn't. I will recheck.

Comment: @Phil I think I included angular-mocks in karam.conf.js. I think I should paste some part of the test and conf file in the question

Comment: I posted something about Angular module architecture. It should be helpful  http://blog.inzynieria.it/getting-start-with-angular-require-grunt-bower-karma-seed

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide here is John Papa's style guide - it's awesome

Comment: thanks, I am looking into both of them. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069261/karma-conf-js-automatic-file-ordering

Comment: @dustin.schultz interesting, that it didn't show up when I tried to search for the problem :P , thanks for the link though.

Comment: @argentum47, your question is interesting but your post is huge. It would benefit from being edited to get to the bottom of the problem…

Comment: well if you could help with that only iff you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Why use two separate files for 10 lines each? The purpose of writing code in separate files is to keep it understandable and maintainable. It would make sense to keep your module `'myAppServices'` in one file.

If you really need to break down your code in multiple files, you should make use of dependency injection and make them each a separate module (see [my patch against your repo](https://github.com/kephas/mdb/commit/00d1ef027aeee8bde4690e8871cdd5448121729c)). Then the order of loading stops being an issue.

Comment: well these are 10 lines here becoz it's some vogus to-do like code, in the real projects, the one I am doing right now, those are more than 100 lines.. although I urge them to break it like in this case, the services, controllers etc as separate modules.. the problem was specific to testing. will try again soon.. thanks.

Comment: It is very good practice to provide a simplified code for the question, but make it clear it is not your final code, so we can understand what your real requirements are.

Comment: See https://github.com/kephas/mdb/commit/00d1ef027aeee8bde4690e8871cdd5448121729c

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a angular-ish solution to this problem.
Still there are two ways to deal with it.

1. Using RequireJS as in @Lukasz 's blog post

and the second one is a dirty one, which I did,

2. Wrote an _config.js file inside services/, controllers/, directives/, which has, for example `angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])` in services/,

   And in the karma.config.js I had to do `files: ['app/services/_config.js', 'app/controllers/_config.js]` . Although the problem still remains because I have to specify the order in which the two `_config.js`'s are to be loaded.

Another way could be to have a single `app/config.js` file with,

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource']);
  angular.module('myAppControllers', ['myAppServices']);
}());
```

and then do `files: ['app/config.js', 'app/controllers/**/*.js', 'app/services/**/*.js']` in karma.conf.js