# Karma check build environment

Tags: karma-runner

In the karma.conf.js you can set what browsers to use e.g. :

```
browsers: [
  "Chrome",
  "Firefox",
  "IE"    
],
```

Is there anyway in this configuration file to see what the build environment is e.g. Windows or Linux and then only run the tests in the appropriate browsers.

I basically don't want to have to keep changing the config file for karma every time I switch a OS.

Comment: Yes. You need to write some code for it, but here's the how to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276239/detecting-environment-when-running-karma/24286880#24286880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into Node.js I found out that you can get the operating system with the following call:

```
var os = require("os");
```

With the os variable I was then able to do simple if/else statements with **os.type**:

```
if(os.type()==='Linux')
```

I would then assign the appropriate browser options to the browser array in the config object.

```
browsers = ["Chrome","Firefox"];
```

All this logic was done inside the Karam.conf.js file but before the **module.exports = function()** call.